# Add a background Image in Constraint Layout

Tags: android

I am trying to add a background image to a Constraint layout, which is the root view of my xml. The image shows if I change the layout to linear or relative but it does not show in a constraint layout. What could be the cause?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_selected_folder_bg">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" <--change these two lines-->
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_selected_folder_bg">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is not showing since there is no content to wrap( as defined by your wrap content )as there are no views inside your viewgroup.

Comment: I am designing for a recycler view item so i have to use wrap content. You are right, adding views to the layout made it visible. Thanks